# Python omits some entries while itereting over dictionary, why?

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, iteration

This is my dictionary and iterating method:

```
update_config_switch = OrderedDict([
    (mode0               , self.mode0Box),
    (config_list[14]     , self.baudrate0Box),
    (config_list[1]      , self.RX_size_uart0Box),
    (config_list[2]      , self.RX_timeout_uart0Box),
    (config_list[3]      , self.TX_size_uart0Box),
    (mode1               , self.mode1Box),
    (config_list[15]     , self.baudrate1Box),
    (config_list[5]      , self.RX_size_uart1Box),
    (config_list[6]      , self.RX_timeout_uart1Box),
    (config_list[7]      , self.TX_size_uart1Box),
    (config_list[8]      , self.RX_size_socket0Box),
    (config_list[9]      , self.RX_timeout_socket0Box),
    (config_list[10]     , self.TX_size_socket0Box),
    (config_list[11]     , self.RX_size_socket1Box),
    (config_list[12]     , self.RX_timeout_socket1Box),
    (config_list[13]     , self.TX_size_socket1Box)])
    print update_config_switch
    for key, val in update_config_switch.iteritems():
        print key
        try:
            index = val.findText(str(key))
            if index >= 0:
                val.setCurrentIndex(index)
        except:
            val.setProperty("value", int(key))
```

This dict should have 16 items, but when I print it or when I print key every time the loop goes I get only 7 results like here:

OrderedDict([('eth', ), (9600, ), (300, ), (500, ), ('dev', ), (115200, ), (1000, )])

Why is that and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that you have 16 _unique_ keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only have 7 results, you must have duplicate keys in your data. You can easily verify how many unique keys you have with this:

```
print(len(set(config_list)))
```

Comment: Well, in fact it might be the case... I didn't thought about it. Thank you